# JQMobile Adding tabs and their Content dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building an android app using PhoneGap and JQmobile.I have to fetch some items and display them as tabs(Even the tab Content is dynamic).Since I don't know the no of items I have to do that dynamically and really don't have any idea as I am newbie.Could Someone help me in doing this .Any JSFiddle link would be helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here re some example to make tab dynamically in JQM

On page load

[JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/w4m2B/) , 
[JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/SJG8W/)

With button click
[JSFiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/V6nHp/)

Create tab dynamically with this. Then detect while a `tab` is clicked, and then bring your dynamic data for each tab accordingly and load in some div.